# starvation by a sequence of short transactions

Tags: database

Why does it say by a sequence of short transactions? If transactions are long there should be no difference, no?

> However, care must be taken to avoid the following scenario. Suppose a
> transaction T2 has a shared-mode lock on a data item, and another
> transaction T1 requests an exclusive-mode lock on the data item. T1
> has to wait for T2 to release the shared mode lock. Meanwhile, a
> transaction T3 may request a shared-mode lock on the same data item.
> The lock request is compatible with the lock granted to T2, so T3 may
> be granted the shared-mode lock. At this point T2 may release the
> lock, but still T1 has to wait for T3 to finish. But again, there may
> be a new transaction T4 that requests a shared-mode lock on the same
> data item, and is granted the lock before T3 releases it. In fact, it
> is possible that there is a sequence of transactions that each
> requests a shared mode lock on the data item, and each transaction
> releases the lock a short while after it is granted, but T1 never gets
> the exclusive-mode lock on the data item. The transaction T1 may never
> make progress, and is said to be starved.

Comment: Where does it say “a sequence of short transactions”?

Comment: Sorry @RBarryYoung for the wrong part that I had quoted, now I corrected that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long transactions (in time) are actually *more* susceptible to blocking problems than short transactions are.  Consequently, it is usually recommended that transactions be designed to hold blocking locks for as short a time as possible.

So, in the scenario above a series of "long" transactions are actually much *more* likely to cause this problem.  However, the writer refers to a series of "short" transactions to emphasize that this problem can happen even when the transactions are short (if there are enough nearly simultaneous compatible transactions).

Comment: Sorry @RBarryYoung, what is the reason that Long transactions (in time) are actually more susceptible to blocking problems than short transactions are?

Comment: @learn9909 because they are holding their locks longer.  The chances that a lock will block another lock request are approximately proportional to how long the lock is held.  If a family has only one shower what are the chances when taking a 5 minute shower that someone else will also want to take a shower?  What if instead it’s a 50 minute shower?  Obviously the longer shower is more likely to “block” someone else from being able to use the shower,